# Magento search function not displaying results correctly

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a issue where the search results are being counted but not showing up in the content section.

I've tried re-indexing and caching. Also checked to make sure products are set as 'catalog, search'.

Not sure if its a bug in theme (Goetze, using template 4).

[This](http://birchgrove.zestdev.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?q=androxx) will return no result which is good.

Whereas [this](http://birchgrove.zestdev.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?q=hemerocallis) shows that there are 23 products in the count but will not display them in grid/list.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
                    <?php
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
{
    // current category is a toplevel category
    $loadCategory = $currentCat;
}
else
{
    // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
    // load the parent category of the current category
    $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
}
$subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren()); 

foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
{
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

    if($cat->getIsActive())
    {
        echo '<a class="parent-categories" href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Fixed this by commenting out all that code except:
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

And search seems to be working properly!

Comment: its better to use a plugin for search. The builtin search is not perfect.

Comment: it seems an error is occuring on the page, you can see no content is loaded after the filters including the 'no search results found' message and more obviously the footer ;) turn on error reporting in your index file and refresh the page and let me know what error message comes up

Comment: Probably a php error (possibly modified template).  Check /var/log/system.log for errors

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getParentId() on null in /home/zestdev/birchgrove.zestdev.com.au/app/design/frontend/ma_goetze/ma_goetze4/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml on line 60